# How does WhatsApp detect who from the contact list uses the app?

Tags: java, android

I'm making a simple chat app for learning purposes. I want my app to pick out who among the contacts uses my app, so only they can be messaged to, just the way whatsapp does it. How do I go about doing this? I'm using Parse for backend.

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp records your phone number when you sign up, so it can add a `phoneNumber` column to its `Users` table. It also gains access to your contacts, which is really just a list of phone numbers. It then crosschecks those phone numbers with the `phoneNumber` column in its `User` table and can thus determine which of your contacts are current users.

Comment: Is this process followed every time the user opens the app? what's the best way to handle performance? I'm surprised how fast WhatsApp is assuming it would have to compare the contacts list against billions of registered users.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. They save phone numbers and details when any body sign up to use their services.

Whats app store these details in their database maybe in their users table.

And when you signup to use their service it reads your contatcs by using android's content provider mechanism and then they compare your contacts with their users tables.

IF any match is found you could see it your list otherwise not.

[This](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/22077138) article might also be useful